# If $\phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ then$ \frac{\phi}{x}\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, distribution-theory

If $\phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ then$ \frac{\phi}{x}\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ ?

Let $\phi$ be a smooth, compactly supported function and $\frac{1}{x}$ be an odd function defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

I want to show that $ \frac{\phi}{x}\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. I need this result to prove that distributional derivative of $log(|x|)$ is $ 1/x$. 
Any hints or reference are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How is $\frac{1}{x}$ defined at $0$?

Comment: Distributional derivative of $\log|x|$ is the principal value $\text{p.v.}\frac{1}{x}$, which is defined as $$ \forall \varphi \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) \ : \ \left< \varphi(x), \text{p.v.}\frac{1}{x} \right> = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac{\varphi(x)}{x} \, dx. $$

Comment: @SangchulLee    Thank you:) So  $\frac{1}{x}$ as a function is not the distributional derivative of $\operatorname{log} |x| $, since $\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \phi(x) \frac{1}{x} dx$ is not well defined for  all $\phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ ?

Comment: @Metamorphosis, That is right. You need certain regularization around the origin to make $\frac{1}{x}$ a bona fide distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is false. If $\phi =1$ in a neighborhood of $0$ and $x(t)=t$ then $\frac \phi x $ is not in $L^{1}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ then, in general, $\frac{1}{x} \phi \not\in L^1(\mathbb R).$

But if $\phi(0) = 0$ then $\frac{1}{x} \phi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ if we set $\left(\frac{1}{x}\phi\right)(0) = \phi'(0).$

As I see that you want to show that $\frac{1}{x} = \left(\ln |x|\right)'$ as a distribution, then first note that $\ln |x| \in L^1(\mathbb R).$ What you then should show is that $x \, (\ln |x|)' = 1$ as distributions.

Make a try, and come back if you don't succeed.